# Error: "gomobile version unknown: binary is out of date, re-install it"

Tags: go, gomobile

I'm encountering an error while working with gomobile, and I'm seeking assistance in resolving it. The specific error message I'm receiving is:

`gomobile version unknown: binary is out of date, re-install it`

To provide some context, here are the steps I've taken:

1. Installed gomobile using [`go install golang.org/x/mobile/cmd/gomobile@latest`]
2. Executed [`gomobile init`]
3. Executed [`gomobile version`]
4. Received the error message mentioned above

Comment: Can you confirm whether the first `gomobile` found in the $PATH (on linux, run `which gomobile`) is the one you just installed (comparing with the output of `go env GOBIN GOPATH`)?

Comment: Yes, for GOBIN, it is empty, and for GOPATH, the value is `home/user_name/go`. @ZekeLu

Comment: What is the output of `which gomobile`?

Comment: And what is the output of `go version -m $(which gomobile)`? (Please add the output to the question).

Comment: The output of above commond is
`/home/harish/go/bin/gomobile: go1.20.4
    path    golang.org/x/mobile/cmd/gomobile
    mod     golang.org/x/mobile
    dep     golang.org/x/mod
    dep     golang.org/x/sync
    dep     golang.org/x/sys
    dep     golang.org/x/tools
    build   -buildmode=exe
    build   -compiler=gc
    build   CGO_ENABLED=1
    build   CGO_CFLAGS=
    build   CGO_CPPFLAGS=
    build   CGO_CXXFLAGS=
    build   CGO_LDFLAGS=
    build   GOARCH=amd64
    build   GOOS=linux
    build   GOAMD64=v1
`

Comment: Thank you for the information. You can edit your question to include the output of `go version -m $(which gomobile)`. It includes information to prove that the binary is not outdated. Anyway, this is an known issue of `gomobile version`. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

For now, the `gomobile version` command only works when `gomobile` is checked out under `GOPATH` and built in `GOPATH` mode. See this reported issue: [x/mobile: gomobile version doesn't work when not checked out under GOPATH or not built in GOPATH mode](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/37654).

If you are interested in the current implementation of `gomobile version`, you can find it here: [runVersion](https://github.com/golang/mobile/blob/3c911d8e3edae4ddeea7f8a6e3ea9eae74f1a81a/cmd/gomobile/version.go#L28-L65).

The conclusion is that you can you can ignore the output of `gomobile version` and go ahead.